# Create junction between OneDrive Music folder and Google Drive on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, junction, directory-junction

I have all of my music stored on Google Drive, which I can access on my laptop at

```
C:\Users\{USERNAME}\Google Drive\Music
```

I am trying to set up a junction between this folder and the OneDrive Music folder, which Windows Explorer is more naturally integrated with (it puts that nice music note icon next to it :)

[image: Music Folder]

The following command fails however:

```
mklink /J C:\Users\{USERNAME}\OneDrive\Music "C:\Users\{USERNAME}\Google Drive\Music"
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

Because, as it states, the OneDrive Music folder already exists.

Is there any way to set up a junction between the two?

Comment: `mklink /j` is used to create a _new_ junction point (name provided in the first directory argument, aka "Link"), that points to an existing directory (second directory argument, aka "Target").  You can't use it to combine two existing folders into one (that's what "Libraries" are for in Windows)

Comment: Do you want both OneDrive and Google Drive to sync the folder? Or do you just want the Music folder to point to your Google Drive music folder?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Didn't they get rid of Libraries in Win10?

Comment: @music2myear Now that you mention it, possibly? -- I never used them. ;)

Comment: @music2myear Checked - They still exist, they're just not shown in explorer by default.  you have to right-click the navigation pane to enable showing them.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I tried to. They were an interesting idea, but they added complexity and confusion and just weren't worth the trouble. IMHO.

Comment: @music2myear I just want the Music folder to point to the Google Drive folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the Music shortcut in File Explorer to point to a different location, try this instead of a Junction:

1. Right-click on the **Music** folder/shortcut and click **Properties**.
2. Open the **Location** tab and select **Move...**.
3. Navigate to `C:\Users\{USERNAME}\Google Drive\Music` and click **Select Folder**.
4. Click **OK** and then choose the appropriate options in the following dialogs which will ask about moving existing items to the new location.

Now, if you still want the explicit OneDrive music folder path to go to the Google Drive music folder for other application's needs, you can delete the existing OneDrive music folder, and then create the SymLink.

However, I don't know if that will cause trouble for OneDrive as it tries syncing the SymLinked location.

Comment: Glad that worked for you.